# CSS Outset/Inset, border and outline

Tags: jquery, html, css

What is exact difference between `CSS outset,inset,border and outline`.
Really confused about this , and what properties can be applied together.?
Which browsers support which of the above properties ?
Short example on above properties will be good.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Border and outline differences

**Border:** The *border edge* surrounds the box border. [Its area](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#box-border-area) counts the total size of the box model. You can specify size (`border-width`), color (`border-color`) and style (`border-style`) for each of the four possible borders (top, right, bottom and left). You can retrieve more info about border properties [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-properties).

**Outline:** Similar to border, but in this case do not take up space, opposite to `border`. Also, you can't style each border separately, the outline style applies to all the four sides of the box. `Outline` can be used together with `border`. Properties you can apply to outline are `outline-color`, `outline-style` and `outline-width`  You can get more info about outline properties [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#dynamic-outlines).

Here's a box model representing `outline` and `border`
[image]

### Border-styles: inset and outset

**Inset:** It's a **[border-style](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-style)**. The border makes the box look as if it was embedded in the canvas. You can use this `border-style` within `border-color` and `border-width`.

[image: Inset border different browsers]

**Outset:** Another **[border-style](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-style)**. The opposite of 'inset': The border makes the box look as if is coming out of the canvas. You can use this `border-style` within `border-color` and `border-width`.

[image: Outset border different browsers]

### Documentation and sources

- [How Do Browsers Render the Different CSS Border Style Values?](http://www.impressivewebs.com/comparison-css-border-style/)
- [W3C Box model specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)
- [W3C Border specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-properties)
- [W3C Outline specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#dynamic-outlines)

Comment: Glad to help! For how the borders look in other browers, the first link in "Documentation and sources" have a lot of examples ;)

Comment: Today many CSS designs use box-shadow. I wonder if `outset` is still being widely used.

Answer (score 0):

these are a property of border

inset: Defines a 3D inset border. The effect depends on the border-color value
outset: Defines a 3D outset border. The effect depends on the border-color value
outline: Set the outline around an element

Answer (score 0):

First answer is great answer. wish we found this two months ago while starting out with html-dom..

Would just like to add: here the big difference is, `border` does not have an `offset` property (a "padding" of a "border" that does not affect the placement of elements) and `outline` cannot be made round with the `-radius` property.